# Pine script plottine lines to connect two lines

Tags: pine-script

I have a code that draws line from high to low or low to high depending on the time when high or low formed during the day. I want to have a connecting line to lines of individual days. How to go about it.

```
study(title="Neely Charts", overlay=true)
//Define variables
string      res = input("D")
var float   h_price = na
var float   l_price = na
var int     h_date = na
var int     l_date = na
var float   h1_price = na
var float   l1_price = na
var int     h1_date = na
var int     l1_date = na



var line z = na
bool isnewtbar = change(time(res)) > 0

//getting lines
if isnewtbar and bar_index > 1 
    h_price := high
    l_price := low
    h_date := time
    l_date := time
   
    z := line.new(x1=h_date, y1=h_price, x2=l_date, y2=l_price, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.none, color=color.black, style=line.style_solid, width=2)
    


if high > h_price
    h_price := high
    h_date := time 


if low < l_price
    l_price := low
    l_date := time
  

if h_date <= l_date
    // high to low
    line.set_xy1(id=z, x=h_date, y=h_price)
    line.set_xy2(id=z, x=l_date, y=l_price)
    line.set_color(id=z, color=color.red)
    
else
    // low to high
    line.set_xy1(id=z, x=l_date, y=l_price)
    line.set_xy2(id=z, x=h_date, y=h_price)
    line.set_color(id=z, color=color.lime)
```

i tried setting previous days price but unable to procede. Can anyboady help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//@version=4

study(title="Neely Charts", overlay=true)
//Define variables
string      res = input("D")
var float   h_price = na
var float   l_price = na
var int     h_date = na
var int     l_date = na
var float   h1_price = na
var float   l1_price = na
var int     h1_date = na
var int     l1_date = na

var line z = na
var line w = na
bool isnewtbar = change(time(res)) > 0

//getting lines
if isnewtbar and bar_index > 1 
    h_price := high
    l_price := low
    h_date := time
    l_date := time
   
    z := line.new(x1=h_date, y1=h_price, x2=l_date, y2=l_price, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.none, color=color.black, style=line.style_solid, width=2)
    w := line.new(x1=line.get_x2(z[1]), y1=line.get_y2(z[1]), x2=l_date, y2=l_price, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.none, color=color.black, style=line.style_solid, width=2)
    
if high > h_price
    h_price := high
    h_date := time 


if low < l_price
    l_price := low
    l_date := time
  

if h_date <= l_date
    // high to low
    line.set_xy1(id=z, x=h_date, y=h_price)
    line.set_xy2(id=z, x=l_date, y=l_price)
    line.set_color(id=z, color=color.red)
else
    // low to high
    line.set_xy1(id=z, x=l_date, y=l_price)
    line.set_xy2(id=z, x=h_date, y=h_price)
    line.set_color(id=z, color=color.lime)

line.set_xy2(id=w, x=line.get_x1(z[0]), y=line.get_y1(z[0]))
line.set_color(id=w, color=color.blue)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Appears solved. Will plot it. You have cleared 99% of the problem. Will ask for small help. How to plot a marker circles at connectors.

Comment: Use the function `plot` with the parameter `style=plot.style_circles`.

Comment: Reference should be what tried but not happening. It's showing multiple plot

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your question. Sorry, I use google translator.

Comment: No issues. You are God send. What should be reference for plotting. h_price or high low of session.

Comment: I have created indicator. Have given you credit for the same.

Comment: According to the rules of the site, you must ask the next question or go to the chat for discussion. My last attempt to help, you need to create two plot, one for lows and one for the highs, the intermediate values are defined as `na`.